# Truncate with condition

Tags: sql, mysql, truncate

truncate  ->this resets the entire table, is there a way via truncate to reset particular records/check conditions.

For ex: i want to reset all the data and keep last 30 days inside the table.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, if the table is separted into partitions, you can truncate only selected partiton, thus not whipe out entire table.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

No, `TRUNCATE` is all or nothing. You can do a `DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <conditions>` but this loses the speed advantages of `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: Thanks, assuming that condition, how do i keep last 10 days data and delete the rest (for say the table has 10 million records), in an optimized manner.

Comment: The speed from TRUNCATE is because it doesn't write to the logs

Comment: Apart from speed truncate also free diskspace, but delete keep disk space.

Answer (score 32):

The short answer is ***no***: MySQL does *not* allow you to add a `WHERE` clause to the `TRUNCATE` statement.  Here's [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) about the `TRUNCATE` statement.

But the good news is that you can (somewhat) work around this limitation.

**Simple, safe, clean but slow solution using `DELETE`**

First of all, if the table is small enough, simply use the `DELETE` statement (it had to be mentioned):

```
1. LOCK TABLE my_table WRITE;
2. DELETE FROM my_table WHERE my_date<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
3. UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The `LOCK` and `UNLOCK` statements are not compulsory, but they will speed things up and avoid potential deadlocks.

Unfortunately, this will be very slow if your table is large... and since you are considering using the `TRUNCATE` statement, I suppose it's because your table is large.

So here's one way to solve your problem using the `TRUNCATE` statement:

**Simple, fast, but unsafe solution using `TRUNCATE`**

```
1. CREATE TABLE my_table_backup AS
      SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_date>=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
2. TRUNCATE my_table;
3. LOCK TABLE my_table WRITE, my_table_backup WRITE;
4. INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM my_table_backup;
5. UNLOCK TABLES;
6. DROP TABLE my_table_backup;
```

Unfortunately, this solution is a bit unsafe if other processes are inserting records in the table at the same time:

- any record inserted between steps 1 and 2 will be lost
- the `TRUNCATE` statement resets the `AUTO-INCREMENT` counter to zero.  So any record inserted between steps 2 and 3 will have an ID that will be lower than older IDs and that might even conflict with IDs inserted at step 4 (note that the `AUTO-INCREMENT` counter will be back to it's proper value after step 4).

Unfortunately, it is not possible to lock the table and truncate it.  But we can (somehow) work around *that* limitation using `RENAME`.

**Half-simple, fast, safe but noisy solution using `TRUNCATE`**

```
1. RENAME TABLE my_table TO my_table_work;
2. CREATE TABLE my_table_backup AS
     SELECT * FROM my_table_work WHERE my_date>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
3. TRUNCATE my_table_work;
4. LOCK TABLE my_table_work WRITE, my_table_backup WRITE;
5. INSERT INTO my_table_work SELECT * FROM my_table_backup;
6. UNLOCK TABLES;
7. RENAME TABLE my_table_work TO my_table;
8. DROP TABLE my_table_backup;
```

This should be completely safe and quite fast.  The only problem is that other processes will see table `my_table` disappear for a few seconds.  This might lead to errors being displayed in logs everywhere.  So it's a safe solution, but it's "noisy".

*Disclaimer*: I am not a MySQL expert, so these solutions might actually be crappy.  The only guarantee I can offer is that they work fine for me.  If some expert can comment on these solutions, I would be grateful.

Comment: Great answer and nice way of working with the limitations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As a response to your question:
"i want to reset all the data and keep last 30 days inside the table."

you can create an event. Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

For example:

```
CREATE EVENT DeleteExpiredLog
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
DELETE FROM log WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Will run a daily cleanup in your table, keeping the last 30 days data available

Answer (score 0):

You can simply export the table with a query clause using datapump and import it back with table_exists_action=replace clause. Its will drop and recreate your table and take very less time. Please read about it before implementing.