# Delete all rows from a table when total row count exceeds a number

Tags: php, mysql, case, sql-delete

I am trying to optimize my queries and I have the following code:

```
<?php
$counter = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM table");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($counter);
$count = $row["c"];
if($count>500){
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table");
}
?>
```

I tried the below syntax as a test and it worked:

```
Select case when (Select count(*) as t from `table`) > 500 then 1 else 2 end
```

But this throws an error:

```
Select case when (Select count(*) as t from `table`) > 500 then (DELETE FROM table) else null end
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELETE FROM table else null end LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

I understand there is a syntax error, but my main question is why the case statement works when I place integers in the condition, but the delete statement throws an error. I tried a select statement and it worked fine:

```
Select case when (Select count(*) as t from `table`) < 500 then (select count(*) from table) else null end
```

Comment: What do you want to delete from the table?

Comment: I want to delete all rows or empty the table @McAdam331

Comment: trucante table `tablename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* wanted to do this with a single `delete`:

```
delete t
     from table t cross join
          (select count(*) as cnt from table t) c
     where c.cnt > 500;
```

Do note (as BWS does) that `truncate table` is more efficient, although you cannot use a `where` clause or `join` with truncate table

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you cannot use any conditions with `truncate table`? So for this particular use case it wouldn't work.

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . I was trying to say that.  I rephrased the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it worked like a charm and true i tried the truncate table and it did not work. Thank you guys for the help this was effective and Gordon if you can explain what cross join does that would be great to help someone else who has never heard of it use.

Comment: Perhaps it was just me that misunderstood. Thanks for rephrasing though. I learned that from this [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704834/truncate-with-condition) question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to delete all the rows from the table, just use "TRUNCATE table"

Comment: But you cannot use any conditions with `truncate` can you? They only want to clear the table when the total row count is greater than 500.

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` statement works with `SELECT` when the `SELECT` statement produces a single value (i.e. it selects only one column and the result set has a single row); it doesn't work otherwise. Obviously, a `DELETE` (or `INSERT`, `UPDATE` etc) never works in that position.