# Can we use truncate with where clause?

Tags: sql

I know that we cannot use where clause with truncate..But i want to delete some records in a table by keeping other records as usual by using truncate...

Can we do that??

Comment: delete only....

Comment: No, you should use `delete` for that

Comment: `truncate` and `delete` have in common the fact that they delete data. However, `delete` does it row-by-row, and so you can qualify it with a `where` clause. `truncate` is, I believe, classified as a DDL statement (Data Definition Language) and affects the table as a whole. Among other things, I can be used to reset any auto-increments. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No, TRUNCATE is all or nothing. You can do a `DELETE FROM <table>
>   WHERE <conditions>` but this loses the speed advantages of TRUNCATE.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704834/truncate-with-condition) thread is a good read :)